# react-draft-wysiwyg Editor Text not showing some styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am using react-draft-wysiwyg text editor, It was working fine previously, but I don't know why text is not showing some styles.

[image]

you can see I applied styles `bold,italic,underline,strikethrough`, but text is only showing `underline` and `strikethrough`. It was working fine before. Could someone help what the issue is?

Comment: Can share a reproducible example?

Comment: @BasvanderLinden, thank you. I created code sand box and found the issue was not there. It was because I removed `  font: normal 14px/16px Open Sans, sans-serif;`  line from `body` selector  and added under *  in `App.scss`